# Cannot dump Django database using pg_dump due to permissions

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu

I want to dump PostgreSQL database to an SQL file. Here is the `pg_dump DB_NAME > dump.sql` command result:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation django_migrations
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.django_migrations IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

When I want to list relations:

```
postgres=# \d
No relations found.
```

List of schemas:

```
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | =UC/postgres        +| 
        |          | root=U/postgres     +| 
        |          | secretusr=U/postgres | 
(1 row)
```

Database list:

```
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges    
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------------------
 db_secret | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres +
           |          |          |             |             | secretusr=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | root=CTc/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres           +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres           +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any user or/and password ? You might find it in config files if you created everything with django orm (never used it btw)

Comment: The `settings.py`file in your Django project must have the configuration.

Comment: @henrikstroem Configuration for what?

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun The database configuration.

Comment: @henrikstroem Yeah, there is DB configuration but I guess this problem is not about the database config in the settings.py

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun No - but if you use the same credentials it should solve the problem.

Comment: @henrikstroem I know the credentials, how can I use them with pg_dump? I tried .pgpass file but it seems it doesn't work.